# How to add a hyperlink to a name in XSLT, with XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML & XSL and am finding it difficult to understand the syntax. I have been working on this issue for the past 2 days, but am not finding a success.

I am writing a XSl file to display a list of movies with its attributes in a table. I have to display the title of the movie as a link to its uri, IF the uri exists for that movie in the XML file .

The code displays the titles, but not as a link.

XML code:

```
<movie>
<title>Die Hard</title>
<uri>http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095016/?ref_=nv_sr_1</uri>
</movie>

<movie>
<title>avatar</title>
</movie>
```

The 2nd movie doesn't have a uri.

XSLT code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          table {
          width: 50%;
          background-color: lightyellow;
          padding: 2px;
          }

        </style>

      </head>

      <body>

        <h2>Movies after 2005</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Director </th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie[year>2005]">
            <xsl:sort select="title"/>          
          </xsl:apply-templates>
          <tr>
          <xsl:if test="self::node()[uri]">
            <!-- Test condition statement for uri tag-->
              <td>
                <a href="{uri}">
                <xsl:value-of select="uri"/>
                  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                </a>
              </td>
          </xsl:if>
          </tr>

          <tr >
            <td colspan="3">
              Number of movies
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="count(//movie)"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </body>

    </html>

      <xsl:template match="movie">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          </td>
          <td>

            <xsl:value-of select="Principaldirector"/>

          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="genre">
              <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried putting the if statement in the title template, but was getting 'invalid child' errors.

Comment: In all likelihood, the problems you are encountering result from some detail or other that looks insignificant to you; by providing only a fragment of your XSLT (or is that really the entire transformation?), you have (probably) omitted the detail that could allow someone to help you.  Try to provide the smallest possible complete running example that illustrates your problem; what you have now isn't it.

Comment: While it's fairly clear what you want to do, the XSL you show is only a fragment and doesn't look like it would work at all.  You need to show the complete XSL (or a [mcve] version of it) as well as the expected XHTML output matching the input provided.

Comment: I put up the entire the xslt code. This is what I have written so far.

Comment: Is it your intention to place the link onto a seperate row or do you mean to wrap it around the <td>{title}</td> for the movie?

Comment: I have to wrap it around the title of the movie. So? If I click on the name of the movie, it directs me to the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your URI test and `<a>` creation into the movie template.

This is not the place for a detailed explaination of context and transformation. For that, you would be better off getting hold of a book and learning the basic concepts of xsl transforms - I can highly recommend Michael Kays books - that's were I started.

In brief, as the xml is being transformed it is processed element-by-element in document order.  Trace through the xml with your figure. When your finger touches the movie tag, this is the point that xsl template (match="movie") is executed. The current context (ie your finger) for that template is at the movie tag, and so your xsl statements are execute relative to this context.

If you follow the context, you'll see that in your original code, the `<xsl:if test..>` is processed relative to the root node as the context is based on `match="/"`. From here, it doesn't see just 1 movie, it see's them all.
If you continue to trace the xml nodes with your finger, you see that the correct place (and context) for your URI test and `<a>` creation is therefore within the `xs:template match="movie"`

And this is what you need to do..

Remove this from the template match="/"

```
      <tr>
      <xsl:if test="self::node()[uri]">
        <!-- Test condition statement for uri tag-->
          <td>
            <a href="{uri}">
            <xsl:value-of select="uri"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </a>
          </td>
      </xsl:if>
      </tr>
```

and in the template match="movie", replace

```
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </td>
```

with

```
 <td>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="uri">
           <a href="{uri}">
             <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
           </a>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
 </td>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the clarification and the help. It finally worked. I wanted to up-vote your answer but cannot do it yet.

Comment: Alternatively, you could mark it as correct answer. Its very common for questioners to forget to do this but it an important indicator of the usefulness of an answer to other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Context is all-important in XSLT, and since you haven't posted enough code to show the context, it seems you haven't fully understood its importance.

Your apply-templates instruction, if it is correct, suggests that the context node for this code fragment is the parent of an (unshown) element called "movies", which we might guess is the parent of the "movie" elements.

I would expect to see your conditional code for handling URIs inside the template for handling the "movie" element, not after it -- but I can't be sure because you haven't shown your desired output. But all I can really say with certainty is that the "xsl:if" code is only going to work if the context item is a "movie", and if that's the case then the apply-templates is wrong.

Comment: Future readers please note: this was an answer to an earlier version of the question. The question has completely changed since this answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

The if-else statement for the hyperlinks had to be outside the root node template match="/".